# use $on() inside computed: {} in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to use checked values of HTML checkboxes in another component like below but I am not getting any output.

```
computed: {
    formated () {
        EventBus.$on('change', function (checkedSkills) {
            console.log(checkedSkills)
        });
    }
},
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Now I am trying to do like below

```
        data() {
            return {
                values: [],
            }
        },
        computed: {
            formated () {
                console.log(this.values)
            }
        },
        created () {
            EventBus.$on('change', function (skillName) {
                this.values = skillName
            });
        },
```

Comment: That computed will never fire. Moreover, this is a terrible idea; if it were to fire, it would add a new change handler every time it did. If you want to add a handler like this, add it in `created` or `mounted` and don't forget to remove it in `destroyed`.

Comment: Thanks @Bert. What should I do in this regard ? Thanks.

Comment: I added some additional info in the original comment.

Comment: @Bert, I updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what the `computed` object is for. `computed` is so that you can create what are essentially variables using other bits of data or logic.

Your new `computed` value `formated` (BTW, it's "formatted" with two t's) is actually a method, not a variable.

You should simply change `computed` to `methods` if you want to log something to the console.

Here is a section in the Vue docs about the differences between computed and methods: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

So instead of what you have now:

```
computed: {
    formated () {
        console.log(this.values)
    }
},
```

You should simply have:

```
methods: {
    formated () {
        console.log(this.values)
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Heffley for your answer. But your solution is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Explain what's wrong dude, I want to be able to help 

Post your whole component in a Git Gist or something.

Comment: Hey, explain how you fixed it for all the other people who come through here looking for an answer.